# How to dial in a regex to detect @usernames

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I have a regex that I've just realized isn't precise enough. Right now I'm using:

`let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@[^\\s]+")`

Which on the following string: `let str = "@alice, @bob, @zack@example.com sara@example.com"`

Is returning`["@alice,", "@bob,", "@zack@example.com", "example.com"]` (notice the commas inside of some of the array elements)

How can I make this more precise so it grabs "@alice" and "@bob" without the trailing comma and ignores the latter 2 examples?

Thanks

Comment: Would this: `@[^\\s]+?(?=,)` work for you? [test](https://regex101.com/r/P05rHu/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\B@[^@\\s]+\\b(?!@\\w)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qdS0tM/1).

It will match

- `\B@` - a `@` not preceded with a letter, digit or `_`
- `[^@\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `@` and whitespace
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!@\w)` - no `@` followed with a letter, digit or `_` is allowed immediately to the right of the current location. A `(?!@)` might suffice though.

Comment: This works well. Thanks Wiktor. Appreciate it. Is it possible to slightly modify so it ensures that the @name is proceeded by a space and nothing else?

Comment: @ZackShapiro Replace `\B` with `(?<!\S)`, ``"(?<!\\S)@[^@\\s]+\\b(?!@\\w)"``

Comment: @ZackShapiro If it worked for you please consider accepting/upvoting the answer.